# Explanation on this Javascript check

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
function doSomething(e) {
    var targ;
    if (!e) var e = window.event; //<<<< what does it do this check?
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
}
```

Why do we need to check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This adds compatibility with older (Internet Explorer?) browsers that didn't support passing the `event` object to handlers but instead defined them on the window object.

Also the `var` is not needed in `var e = window.event` because it's already declared (parameter).

It can also be written as `e = e || window.event;`

Answer (score 1):

Basically this if checks if `e` variable is set. If it isn't - it is assigned a value of window.event (the window event that happened)

Comment: so do we really need to check this? can we just assume that that 'e' will get a value either way?

Comment: @YoniGeek What the other guys (Shurdoof and Alex R.) said, it's for browser compatibility, `e` will be set in standard compliant browsers, but not window.event (IE only), so if you assign without checking in W3C browser you'll get an empty value in `e`